# MySQL ha dicho: #1364 - Field 'id' doesn't have a default value

Tags: mysql

Estoy creando un procedimiento almacenado:

```
    DELIMITER $$
    CREATE PROCEDURE procesar_solicitud_os(id_usuario int, id_proveedor int,token varchar(50), autonumero int, observaciones varchar(200))
    BEGIN
        DECLARE solicitud INT;
        
        DECLARE registros INT;
        
        DECLARE tmp_id_servicio INT;
        DECLARE tmp_cantidad INT;
        DECLARE a INT;
        SET a = 1;
        
        
        CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tbl_temp_tokenuser(
            id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
            id_servicio INT,
            cantidad INT
        );
        
        SET registros =(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM compras_temp_solicitud_os WHERE token_usuario = token);
        
        IF registros > 0 THEN
        
            INSERT INTO tbl_temp_tokenuser (id_servicio,cantidad) SELECT id_servicio,cantidad FROM compras_temp_solicitud_os WHERE token_usuario = token;
            
            INSERT INTO compras_solicitudes_os(autonumero,id_solicitante,id_proveedor,observacion)VALUES(autonumero,id_usuario,id_proveedor,observaciones);
            SET solicitud = LAST_INSERT_ID();
            
            INSERT INTO compras_solicitudes_os_detalle (id_solicitud_so,id_servicio,cantidad) SELECT (solicitud) as id_solicitud_so,id_servicio,cantidad FROM    compras_temp_solicitud_os
            WHERE token_usuario = token;
            
            WHILE a <= registros DO
                SELECT id_servicio,cantidad INTO tmp_id_servicio,tmp_cantidad FROM tbl_temp_tokenuser WHERE id = a;
                
                SET a=a+1;
            END WHILE;
            
            DELETE FROM compras_temp_solicitud_os WHERE token_usuario = token;
            TRUNCATE TABLE tbl_temp_tokenuser;
            SELECT * FROM compras_solicitudes_os WHERE id = solicitud;
            
        ELSE
        
            SELECT 0;
        
        END IF;
         
           
    END;$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Al ejecutarlo me arroja el siguiente error:

> > Falló la siguiente consulta: "SET @p0='4'; SET @p1='13'; SET @p2='8f14e45fceea167a5a36dedd4bea2543'; SET @p3='1305'; SET
> > @p4='test'; CALL `procesar_solicitud_os`(@p0, @p1, @p2, @p3, @p4); "
>
> MySQL ha dicho: #1364 - Field 'id' doesn't have a default value

Ya revise y todas las sentencias Where se cumplen y los parámetros son los correctos, me podrían indicar a que hace referencia el error

Comment: Saludos. El error ocurre con la tabla **tbl_temp_tokenuser** el cual su **id* lo tienes **not null**; es el **insert** en esta la que genera el error; lo tienes similar a https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/example-auto-increment.html pero por lo que veo es lo que genera el error.

Comment: Saludos Roberto, entendido revisare la documentación proporcionada y te estaré comentando el avance.

Comment: Saludos de nuevo; me percato tienes otros insert; igual da revisión de esas tablas donde lo realizas, quizas una de ellas sea que lo genera.

Comment: Si, depurare insert por insert así daré con el que genera el error